# how to solve options are not supported on this platform error in docker volume create

Tags: windows, docker

I try to create docker volume named 'cifstest' to a mapped network directory on windows server 2019 using the following command :

`docker volume create   --driver local  --opt type=cifs   --opt device=//decvice-ip/folder --opt "o=username=username,password=password"   cifstest`

and I got this error:

`Error response from daemon: create cifstest: options are not supported on this platform`

does it means that windows does not support docker volume's options ?

my docker version is :
`Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my need:

I created a SMB mapping from the container itself to SMB share that I defined in remote server.

important! before creating the SMB mapping define the right credentials to connect to the SMB .

```
$username = "remoteHost\remoteUserName"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "remoteHostPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password)
New-SmbGlobalMapping -RemotePath \\remoteHost\SMBName  -Credential $psCred -LocalPath D:
```

And don't forget to give the SMB (in the remote host) full control share access to Everyone.